# Fourier transform on forced linear harmonic oscillator

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm having trouble solving the following equation:

$\ddot x + \omega^2 x = a \sin \Omega t$, where $t >0$, $\omega \neq \Omega$, $x(0+) = 0 = \dot x(0+)$.

It is asked to be done by Fourier transform. If I use

$\mathcal{F}\{f^{(2)} \} = (i \omega)^2 \mathcal{F}\{f\} $

on the interval $(0, \infty]$, I end up with zero on the left side of the equation. So I don't think I can use this since I don't think $x$ or $\dot x$ tends to $0$ as $t$ goes to infinity. Am I missing something about $x$ that is implied without saying? At least I think it should be reasonable to guess that $x$ should be a trigonometric function. Any hints are very appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The parameter $\omega$ in the differential equation and the $\omega$ that appears in $\mathcal{F}\{f^{(2)}\}$ are not the same. It's better to call the parameter $\omega_0$ so that your ODE is $\ddot x+\omega_0^2x=a\sin\Omega t$ and write the Fourier transform of $f^{(2)}$ properly as: $\forall \omega\in\mathbb{R},\ \mathcal{F}\{f^{(2)}\}(\omega)=(i\omega)^2\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega)$ (always write the quantifiers so that you really know what you're talking about and not just do _formal_ meaningless mumbo jumbo with symbols).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I suspected that this was the case, thanks alot! And yes, I will be more specific with quantifiers ;)